# Get popular articles over last week rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

hoping this is a relatively simple solution. I have a posts table and an likes table. users can like a post, so posts has_many likes and likes belong_to posts.

With that in mind, how would I go about getting the most popular posts (by likes) from the last week? I'd like to keep the solution down to just a query, as limiting the query to just the last week should keep any scaling issues at bay (i think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend doing this with a named scope.

Your SQL query would be something like:

```sql
SELECT post_id, count(post_id) as count FROM "likes" 
GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY count desc LIMIT 3
```

You could get this in your Like class with the following:

```ruby
scope :popular, select("post_id, count(post_id) as count").group(:post_id).order("count desc").limit(3)
```

Then, when you want the most popular posts, you would do

```
@popular = Like.popular
@popular[0].post_id # this will be the id of the Post
@popular[0].count   # this will be the count of likes for that Post
```

An advantage of this is that it will show the most popular posts over all time.  If you wanted to limit the likes to those given within the last week, you would put the select statement above into a `lambda {}` and use a `where("created_at < ?", DateTime.now - 1.week)` before the `select`.  You could even pass in an argument to control how far back to filter.  More details see the [ActiveRecord guide details on passing arguments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need a variable representing the datetime one week ago. I think it would be something like:

```
one_week_ago = Time.now - 1.week
```

You're going to have to calculate the number of likes in the last week for each post and store it in a variable before you compare all the posts for the top n posts.

```
likes_for_last_week = post.likes.where("created_at > ?", one_week_ago).count
```

You could store all these in an array:

```
[[post,likes_for_last_week][post,likes_for_last_week]...]
```

Then sort using the <=> operator.

Pardon me for being brief but as I'm a fairly novice programmer this much guidance took a fair amount of research on my part.